# Local variable 'cid' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

Im trying to add a payment method.
I also add Getway and Get Success Message.
Now I want to show success message with cid and name in my template page.
When I want to get context data, I got This Error.
** Local variable 'cid' referenced before assignment. **
My code:

```
class CheckoutSuccessView(View):
    model = Transaction
    template_name = 'success.html'

    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # return render(request, self.template_name,{'transaction':transaction})
        return HttpResponse('nothing to see')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = self.request.POST
        
        
        try:
            Transaction.objects.create(
                name = data['value_a'],
                cid = data['value_b'],
                tran_id=data['tran_id'],
                val_id=data['val_id'],
                amount=data['amount'],
                card_type=data['card_type'],
                card_no=data['card_no'],
                 ...
                 ...

            )
            messages.success(request,'Payment Successfull')

            name = data['value_a'],
            cid = data['value_b'],
            
            

            

        except:
            messages.success(request,'Something Went Wrong')

        
        

            
        context = {
                'cid': cid,
                'name' : name
                 }

        return render(request, 'success.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may miss block or put extra indentation.
Define it before try block.

You may try this:

```
class CheckoutSuccessView(View):
    model = Transaction
    template_name = 'success.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # return render(request, self.template_name,{'transaction':transaction})
        return HttpResponse('nothing to see')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = self.request.POST

        name = data['value_a'],
        cid = data['value_b'],

        try:
            Transaction.objects.create(
                name = data['value_a'],
                cid = data['value_b'],
                tran_id=data['tran_id'],
                val_id=data['val_id'],
                amount=data['amount'],
                card_type=data['card_type'],
                card_no=data['card_no'],
                 ...
                 ...

            )
            messages.success(request,'Payment Successfull')

        except:
            messages.success(request,'Something Went Wrong')

        context = {
                'cid': cid,
                'name' : name
                 }

        return render(request, 'success.html', context)
```

I think you are using sslcommerz-lib for SSLCOMMERZ PAYMENT GATEWAY.